# /tmp folder and gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, debian, maemo

I am using the maemo Operating System and the GCC compiler. I have an error when I compile an application: there is no enough space on /tmp. I have 10% of my space free so I don't understand why this happens.. anyway, is it possible to change the GCC configuration in order to use another folder (in another partition)?

Answer (score 30):

Set your `TMPDIR` environment variable to where you want GCC to put your temporary files. Or, use the `-pipe` flag to keep temporary files (except object files) in memory.

Comment: In that case I hope you'll remember to accept the answer. @vah

Comment: I have no environment variable named `TMPDIR` shall I make a new one?

Comment: Note that the TMPDIR has to actually exist, or GCC will silently keep using `/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `/tmp` directory is mounted as a `tmpfs` filesystem.  This means that the files in `/tmp` are actually stored in memory, not on disk.  If this is the case `/tmp` will be limited to what you can fit in memory+swap, and everything in `/tmp` will be lost across reboots.

Use `mount` or `df -T` to see how `/tmp` is mounted.

Comment: /tmp's tmpfs is limited to a a rather small percentage of physical memory, by default, on Debian at least.

Comment: ^ I don't know how things were in 2012 (though a cursory Google suggests this was the case even in 2006:), but in most cases, `/tmp` and `/dev/shm` are by default capped at a whopping 50% of available RAM, so I don't think there's much need to worry about that.